# How to resolve Netbios hostname on Fedora

Tags: fedora, samba, netbios

Tutorial: [How to enable Linux machines to resolve Windows hostnames](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-linux-machines-to-resolve-windows-hostnames/).

On Fedora, installing **samba-winbind-clients** package is not sufficient.

```
$ wbinfo -N windowsbox
failed to call wbcResolveWinsByName: WBC_ERR_WINBIND_NOT_AVAILABLE
Could not lookup WINS by name windowsbox
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that winbind service is not running.

Solution:

```
sudo systemctl enable winbind.service
sudo systemctl start winbind.service
```